# Opengl: Texture gone wrong

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, texture2d

I'm trying to texture a square polygon(composed of two triangles) and get the following result.

texture coordinates:
1 - (0,0)
2 - (1,0)
3 - (1,1)
4 - (0,1)

Vertex Setup:
[image]

These are the texture parameters that was used. `mImage` is just a handle to the image.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, mImage->width(), mImage->height(), 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mImage->data());
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Actual Image:
[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Looks like your texture coordinates are only being interpolated in one direction on both of your triangles. There is a lot more info needed to answer this question, particularly your vertex setup.

Comment: I'm gonna upvote this post for the paint image. It's outrageous.

Comment: @Andon M.Coleman I have added my vertex setup and also named the vertices. The corresponding texture coordinates are put up too. From what you hinted, I think I have messed up coordinates.

Comment: @PawełStawarz Yeah well, sorry for the awkward paint drawing. I guess it was the fastest way to show what I was trying to do.

Comment: Actually, that's still not entirely what I was looking for. It's quite a bit more detailed in some respects. If you are using vertex arrays, I am interested in seeing the commands you use to setup the pointers. If it is immediate mode, then the `glTexCoord* (...)` calls.

Comment: give you drawing function too.

Comment: I fixed the issue. There was a problem with my glBufferData function for texture coords. Instead of pointing to the texcoords' data, it was pointing to the color arrays.